# how can I save a string data to TFRecord?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tfrecord

when save to TFRecord, I use:

```
def _int64_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))


def _bytes_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))


def _float_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=value))
```

and

```
one_example = tf.train.Example(
    features=tf.train.Features(
        feature={
            "image": _bytes_feature(img.tobytes()),
            "label": _bytes_feature(label.tobytes()),
            "file_name": _bytes_feature(this_city_file_name), #this line doesn't work
            "nb_rows": _int64_feature(nb_rows), 
            "nb_cols": _int64_feature(nb_cols), 
            "index_i": _int64_feature(i), 
            "index_j": _int64_feature(j),
        }
    )
)
```

and **this_city_file_name** has a type of string
when I ran this code, that result in an error:

**TypeError: 'xxxxxxx' has type , but expected one of: ((,),)**

simply use bytes(this_city_file_name) will also result an error:

**TypeError: string argument without an encoding**

when load from TFRecord, I use

```
features = tf.parse_single_example(serialized_example,
                                   features={
                                       "image": tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
                                       "label": tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
                                       "file_name": tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
                                       "nb_rows": tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
                                       "nb_cols": tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
                                       "index_i": tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
                                       "index_j": tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
                                   },
                                   )
```

I know how to save int and np.array type to and read from TFRecord 
But how can I save and load **string** data from TFRecord?

Comment: Hey, so were you ever able to fix this issue? The code seems correct, so it might be that there is some corrupted character or empty character in one row of your dataset.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but you have to convert `this_city_file_name` to a bytes object. Check out this [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/tfrecord)

Here is the relevant code :

```
print(_bytes_feature(b'test_string'))
print(_bytes_feature(u'test_bytes'.encode('utf-8')))
```